# Successive http calls in angularjs using success

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am firing an http post and upon its success firing another post.
Now I need to collect responses from both the calls and compare them.

Problem I am facing is the code written inside success of second call isn't getting executed, the debugger is also behaving strangely. Only the first line of code in second success is executed which is a console and debugger isn't going to other lines.

```
 this._docgenService.getTemplate(alreadyExistingTemplateId).success(
                serverTemplate => {

                    console.log(serverTemplate);
                    return this._docgenService.getXMLParts(files).success(
                    localTemplate => {
                        console.log(localTemplate);
                        var addItemToMappingContract = true;
                        for (var i = 0; i < localTemplate.tags.length; i++) {
                            console.log("for loop");
                            for (var j = 0; j < serverTemplate.mappings[0].templateElements.contentTexts.length; j++) {
                                if (localTemplate.tags[i].name === serverTemplate.mappings[0].templateElements.contentTexts[j].name) {
                                    addItemToMappingContract = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (addItemToMappingContract === true) {
                                var tempContextText: Mapping.IContentText;
                                 angular.copy(serverTemplate.mappings[0].templateElements.contentTexts[0], tempContextText);
                                serverTemplate.mappings[0].templateElements.contentTexts.add(
                                {});
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    );


                })
```

Answer (score 0):

When hitting the success function (after the first asynchronous function has been invoked) you are returning the second asynchronous call. You are handing the second promise instead of executing it. Try removing the `return` from the promise:

```
 this._docgenService.getXMLParts(files).success(
                    localTemplate => { ...
```

Comment: Infact I had it without return before but everywhere I saw blogs saying return the promise. Both are giving same behavior for me.